# Applying Lloyd Relaxation to vertices within Three.js

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js, vertices

I have generated randomly positioned vertices in `Three.js` like so:

[image: vertices]

Using [Lloyd's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd's_algorithm) I'd like to apply relaxation to make the spacing of these vertices more even.

The vertices are in an array like so, with each vertice having an `x`, `y`, and `z` coordinate:

[image: array of vertices]

In Three.js, I'm not really sure how to do this, or if there's a simpler method. I understand there's a library to do this, except then I'm not sure how to actually apply that to this array specifically. I was looking to create voronoi diagrams, and this was one of the first steps.

Comment: You can either perform the relaxation beforehand and then [create the geometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Geometry), or you can create the geometry and then [update](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things) the vertices.

Comment: I know I can update the geometry, but my main problem is understanding the algorithm. I think I would loop through each vertex and apply a transformation, but I'm not sure what this transformation would be.

Comment: So are you asking how Lloyd relaxation works?